# How to change child entity into parent entity?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with changing a child entity into parent entity.
In my Item class I have a nagivation property to "Parent item".
Now I want to update my child and "unpin" it from parent.

I found this: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13913

But maybe there is something a "tricky way" to do what I want.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    public Item Parent { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Children { get; private set; }
}

public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Item>().HasMany(x => x.Children).WithOne(x => x.Parent).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

public async Task UpdateAsync(Item item)
{
    item.Parent = null;
    _context.Items.Update(item);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I want change(update) from:

- Item 1

  - Item 2

To:

- Item 1
- Item 2

But setting null on navigation property causes a deletion of child.
Additionally I want to delete all children when I delete parent - it works now and I want to keep this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Item class has to have a ParentId to create a relationship between it and its parent.
if you add it then set it null you problem may solve.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    public string ParentId {get; set;}
    public Item Parent { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try setting the entity's state before saving when you don't want it to be deleted

```
var entry = _context.Entry(Item1);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

It's not pretty, but it should do the work.

[EntityEntry.State Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.state?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_EntityEntry_State)

[EntityEntry<TEntity> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry-1?view=efcore-2.1)

[DbContext.Entry Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.entry?view=efcore-2.1)

Comment: EF still delete object. Adding ParentId property worked.